# Understanding CFLs in Electrical Circuits

Tags: voltage, amperage, short-circuit, light, electricity

I wish to have a better understanding of how CFLs work in a electrical circuit like a home.

A CFL broke a little towards the top when I touched it.

I noticed it light up at the bottom and then made a noise. The top near the break did not light up. Was this a short circuit? Could of it damaged something on the same circuit due to excessive amperage or voltage being put back into the circuit when this failure happened?

Answer (score 1):

> A CFL broke a little towards the top when I touched it.

So, it's a mechanical failure of the glass tube? That means the near-vacuum is gone and the mercury filling now sticks to the electrodes.

The electrodes may still light up and also light the fluorescent powder at the ends of the glass tube. But they can't get the gas filling to conduct by itself anymore as the gas pressure is too high for that.

In low-pressure mercury gas, the electrons are accelerated by the electric field so much they can crack another electron (or more) from a mercury atom when they hit it. That results in an avalance effect, which enables current flow. At higher pressure, they hit the next atom before they are fast enough.

Comment: These are the kinds of questions that can lead to so much good learning about physics. It's too bad that people don't make the most of it. Here, we could start back with Crookes' maltese cross anode shape in a CRT, who then argued (1897) that the "beam" was a particle. Hertz reasoned that if it was a charged particle, then it should be deflected by an applied electric field. But he failed to achieve any deflection in 1891. Another Hertz experiment, unknown to him producing x-rays, led Hertz to conclude it had to be some kind of wave and not a particle. And so much more. +1. Sadly, few care.

Comment: @Janka Was there any electrical short circuit or excess voltage/amperage in the situation?

Comment: Unlikely. If the electrodes burned out, it was because they were becoming brittle from running in an oxygen/nitrogen atmosphere once the glass was broken.

Comment: @jonk: We have very few questions about basic principles, yes. I think it's because they are somewhat inaccessible to simple questions.

Comment: I don't imagine we could get into all that here. I agree. Though I admit that I like to try and use someone's curiosity as a segue for an answer that unearths some interesting earlier contexts to add. I usually don't care if the OP cares. Others may. So it's fun to add an "odd resonance" here and there when and where I see a moment of curiosity from someone.